# C# regex not working properly

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to write a regex which I know finds 6 matches, since I used many regex engines to check it. The problem is with the `Match-> nextMatch`, or it's smarter equivalent:

```
Match m= regex.Match(data,nextRelevantIndex);
```

when I use the methods above I get *3 results* out of *6*.
however when I use

```
  MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(data);

  foreach (Match m in mc)
  {
     // …
  }
```

it iterates over 6 times.
Unfortunately I cannot use this version, since I'm changing the data I run on, and it will be much more difficult for me than to use

`regex.Match(data,nextRelevantIndex);`

Is it a known problem in C#? what is the best solution for this?

the regex is:

```
((?:var\s+)?[\w_]+\s*=)?\s*\$\.import\s*\((?:[""'']([^''"";)]+)[""''])(?:\s*,\s*(?:[""'']([^''"";)]+)[""'']))?\s*\)(\.[^;]+;)?
```

The string is:

```
//from project
$.import("sap.hana.ide.catalog.plugin.performance.server.lib", "helpers");
var h = $.sap.hana.ide.catalog.plugin.performance.server.lib.helpers;

//basic example
$.import("a.b","math"); //var otherHashVar= new otherHash();
$.a.b.math.max(1);  //otherHashVar.max(1);
alert($.a.b.math.a);//alert(otherHashVar.a);

//a bit more complex
var z=$.import("a.b.c","x"); // var z=new otherHash(); -> no additional fixes to be done
z.foo(); 

//another variation
$.import ("a.b","myLib").x(); // similar to first 
//var otherHashVar=new OtherHash();
//otherHashVar.x();

var z=$.import("a\b\c.xsjs"); 

z=$.import("a\b\c.xsjs").a.b.c++;
```

and the code is:

```
       while(m.Success){

            m = r.Match(data, m.Index + m.Length);
        }
```

since I'm not currently modifying the data (will do when I will success to have 6 matches)

Comment: Depending on your regular expression starting from a different index could lead to different results.  So, this can not be answered if you don't include your regular expression at the very least and preferably also an example string you run it on that produces the problem.

Comment: _since I'm changing the data I run on_? Strings in .Net are immutable. I don't think than you can change the string that the regex is currently using.

Comment: what do you really want? by `regex.Match(data,nextRelevantIndex);`  i assumed you want nth match. please describe more about your problem

Comment: Please have a look at [this demo](http://goo.gl/JhW43V). Does it return the correct groups/matches that you expect? Note, it is *your* regex, and there are 6 matches. You can get them all with a mere `var res = r.Matches(data).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();` or similar. If you need to replace, you need to check if the groups are set correctly. Then, you'd need a `Regex.Replace`. Please describe the *actual* problem you are having, what your real goal is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is elsewhere in your program.

The following writes 6 matches to console:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    String data="//from project\r\n$.import(\"sap.hana.ide.catalog.plugin.performance.server.lib\", \"helpers\");\r\nvar h = $.sap.hana.ide.catalog.plugin.performance.server.lib.helpers;\r\n//basic example\r\n$.import(\"a.b\",\"math\"); //var otherHashVar= new otherHash();\r\n$.a.b.math.max(1);  //otherHashVar.max(1);\r\n\ralert($.a.b.math.a);//alert(otherHashVar.a);\r\n\r\n//a bit more complex\rv\n\r z=$.import(\"a.b.c\",\"x\"); // var z=new otherHash(); -> no additional fixes to be done\rz\n.foo(); \r\n\r//another variation\r$.import (\"a.b\",\"myLib\").x(); // similar to first \r\n//var otherHashVar=new OtherHash();\r\n//otherHashVar.x();\r\n\r\nvar z=$.import(\"a\\b\\c.xsjs\"); \r\n\r\nz=$.import(\"a\\b\\c.xsjs\").a.b.c++;"   
        ;
    //System.Console.WriteLine(data);
    String expr="((?:var\\s+)?[\\w_]+\\s*=)?\\s*\\$\\.import\\s*\\((?:[\"\"'']([^''\"\";)]+)[\"\"''])(?:\\s*,\\s*(?:[\"\"'']([^''\"\";)]+)[\"\"'']))?\\s*\\)(\\.[^;]+;)?";
    Regex r=new Regex(expr);
    Match m=r.Match(data);
    while(m.Success){
        System.Console.WriteLine("Match found ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        m = r.Match(data, m.Index + m.Length);
    }

}


}
```

[Dot Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cCuqMc)

Also you state that you can't use foreach match in matchcollection because you are modifying your data.  What modification are you doing, and have you considered using `Regex.Replace`?

Comment: I don't think that there is something wrong. i just get a string and look for Match in it.

Comment: @Mary Just copy paste the above into your VS, compile, and run.  Should make it clear if it's a issue with version or build environment immidiately.

Comment: I did it, and it works fine. but for some reason when I get the string dynamically it is not working

Comment: @mary print the string.  Also print the matches you get from the string.